# How to move a software without having the installation setup?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-2000

A friend of mine asked me to propose him a way to transfer an old software which he uses in a windows 2000 machine to a new system.

I can think of 2 methods:

1. Making an image from his windows 2000 system and make a copy of the whole system on a new system. but I'm not sure if this works?
2. Searching for the library dependencies of the software and move all the binaries and libraries to the new system.

I'm not sure which one to choose.

Comment: I couldn't add the win2000 tags. sorry for the bad tagging.

Comment: Depends on the software, some older software ran from the program folder with few dependencies, it just depends, try copying the program folder to the new system and run the software, see if it throws errors and what they are.

Comment: Best way I think will be to convert the old machine to a Virtual Machine and then run this inside the new machine. Some info on how to do this at http://superuser.com/questions/346959/converting-a-windows-2000-physical-machine-to-a-virtual-machine

Comment: If you mean moving to another existing win2000 machine, copy program folder, look for registry entries (both under hklm/software and hkcu/software). If you mean getting rid of the old hardware, convert it to a virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 will usually not work.
If a program stores all its files in its own folder inside C:\Program Files\myprog or whatever, you can just move this folder to another system with identical dependencies or whatever the program depends on (architecture, hdd type, libraries, serial number...).
But as soon as the app starts to store config files or dll libraries in the Windows folder or at any other places, it is hard to find them.
If now the program also uses the Registry to store some information, you can almost forget it!

You see, just moving a program's folder worked maybe back in DOS time (even then not always), but the newer such an application is, the more likely is it to have some files or info spread over different locations or to depend on not-so-easy-copyable information (e.g. some copy protections)